# Apache Sling tutorial, Slingbucks 404 error

Tags: java, apache, maven, osgi-bundle, sling

I'm currently trying to follow the Slingbucks tutorial within this [README](https://apache.googlesource.com/sling/+/c7047ff38bb6e866e35c04a1485b148e71830cce/samples/slingbucks/README.txt).

I've gone through the step of building the Sling source code.  When I build the Slingbucks project, I see that the bundle exists within the Felix container when I go to system/console.  But when I try following the next step of going to  http://localhost:8080/content/slingbucks/public/orders.html, I get a 404 error.  I'm running this on Windows and I'm using Java 8 and Maven 3.3.9.  Any help for resolving this will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Yes, the bundle is in the active state

Edit: So now I've run into a new issue, where after I go through the steps of submitting an order, I have no confirmed orders under slingbucks/private/confirmed.html.  I just see a page with the title "Confirmed Orders" with no order's underneath it.  Also, I get a 403 error when I try and access /content/slingbucks/readonly/options/fields, but this is less of an issue for me.

Comment: So I decided to run the Slingbucks project from within the samples folder of the Sling project and it's working correctly now.  I had initially created a separate directory where I would build the Slingbucks project, separated from the Sling application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.  I used the sling standalone application and the slingbucks project from the source code download.  Ran the build and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

please check if the bundle is in active state( ie. all the dependencies are satisfied.
If the bundle is still in RESOLVED state ,it wont work.